# How to pass arguments to eventListener function and later remove that function?

Tags: javascript

```
if(allSquares[block].classList.toggle("showPath"))
        {
            allSquares[block].addEventListener('click', moveAbleBoxes);
            moveAbleBoxes.bind(this, i, j, piece);
            //moveAbleBoxes(this, i, j, piece);
        }
        else {
            allSquares[block].removeEventListener('click', moveAbleBoxes);
            console.log('listener removed');
        }
```

I somehow want to pass those argument to function 'moveAbleBoxes' and later i also want to remove that eventListener. so i'm not able to use anonymous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call bind on a function it returns a new function with the bound properties. Just store the function so you can retrieve it later to remove the event handler.

```
var moveAbleBoxesB = {};
...
    if(allSquares[block].classList.toggle("showPath"))
    {
        moveAbleBoxesB[block] = moveAbleBoxes.bind(this, i, j, piece);
        allSquares[block].addEventListener('click', moveAbleBoxesB[block]);
        //moveAbleBoxes(this, i, j, piece);
    }
    else {
        allSquares[block].removeEventListener('click', moveAbleBoxesB[block]);
        console.log('listener removed');
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. now its working. but 
moveAbleBoxesB[block] = moveAbleBoxes.bind(block, i, j, piece);
the values i'm sending are (38, 7, 7, 'abc'), and inside function i'm receiving
(7, 7, 'abc', [object MouseEvent]) the first value i,e 38 is lost.